# What is the relationship between the representations of ${\frak sl}(2;\Bbb C)$ when viewed as real Lie algebra or complex Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is well known that we can classify all the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ as follows:

> Theorem. For each integer $m \geq 0$, there is an irreducible complex representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2 ; \mathbb{C})$ with dimension $m+1 .$ Any two irreducible complex representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2 ; \mathbb{C})$ with the same dimension are isomorphic.

I want to know whether the classification of the representations of a complex Lie algebra (such as $\mathfrak{sl}(2 ; \mathbb{C})$) stays unchanged when it is viewed as a real Lie algebra?

ps: Some physics books mentioned that every $mn$ dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$  (the Lie algebra of Lorentz group) can be obtained by the tensor product of two irreducible representations of  $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ with dim-$m$ and dim-$n$ respectively. However, $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ as a REAL Lie algebra, and this classification is clearly different from the theorem above. I am wondering whether some of these representation is reducible or the classification of irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$ as a real Lie algebra is different from when it is viewed as a complex Lie algebra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fact 1**: If $\mathfrak g$ is a *real* Lie algebra, then the complex representations of $\mathfrak g$ are in $1$-to-$1$-correspondence with the complex representations of its complexification $\mathfrak g_\mathbb C := \mathfrak g \otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$.

See e.g. [Bijection between the complex representations of a real Lie algebra and the complex representations of its complexification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/410391/96384). Also compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384 for what this correspondence means, in particular the somewhat surprising consequence that mutually non-isomorphic $\mathfrak g$ can, to a large extent, have "the same" representations, namely, if they have the same complexification. E.g. $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{su}_2$, the two real forms of their common complexification $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$; or $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb R), \mathfrak{su}_3$ and $\mathfrak{su}_{1,2}$, the three real forms of their common complexification $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb C)$. [My answer in the second link emphasizes that this correspondence does *not* respect conjugation among the representations, but for now let's marvel at how much it *does* respect.]

**Fact 2**: Viewing a complex Lie algebra $L$ (of complex dimension $n$, say) as a real Lie algebra (of dimension $2n$) is a process called "scalar restriction", and for sake of clarity should sometimes be denoted with a functor notation, e.g. $R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R} (L)$. It is of utmost importance to be aware that:

**2A)** This scalar restriction is *not* an inverse to scalar extension (complexification) which we saw in Fact 1. Rather, for a large class of Lie algebras including the semisimple ones, we have that

$$(R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R}(L))_\mathbb C \simeq L \oplus L$$

i.e. restriction of a complex Lie algebra followed by extension gives out a sum of two copies of the complex Lie algebra we started with.

(But in general, the other way around will *not* do that. In fact, e.g. for $\mathfrak g := \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$, the real Lie algebra $$R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R} (\mathfrak g_\mathbb C)$$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathfrak g$ itself, nor to any direct sum of copies thereof.)

**2B)** To find, for a given complex Lie algebra $L$, a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that $\mathfrak g_\mathbb C \simeq L$ (i.e. finding "an actual inverse" of complexification) is a harder task. Such a $\mathfrak g$ is called a "real form" of $L$. Not all complex Lie algebras have real forms. All *semisimple* complex Lie algebras do have real forms, but unless the Lie algebra is $0$, they are *never unique*. (At the end of fact 1 I listed all real forms of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ for $n=2,3$. Bigger complex Lie algebras tend to have even more mutually non-isomorphic real forms.)

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3975561/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895802/96384.

---

Now to apply this to your problem. By a funny coincidence, indeed the Lorentz Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, a $6$-dimensional real Lie algebra, is isomorphic to $R_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C))$, the scalar restriction of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. Consequently we have $1$-to-$1$-correspondences

complex reps of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ $\leftrightarrow$ complex reps of $R_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C))$ $\stackrel{\text{Fact }1}\leftrightarrow$ complex reps of $(R_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)))_\mathbb C$ $\stackrel{\text{Fact }2A}\leftrightarrow$ complex reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$

So you see, via the "doubling" process in 2A, the representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ *viewed as real Lie algebra* are actually in correspondence with the the respresentations of the complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. (And similarly for any semisimple complex Lie algebra $L$, the complex reps of $R_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}(L)$ are the complex reps of $L \oplus L$.)

Now one can take this further:

**Fact 3**: If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two semisimple complex Lie algebras, then every irreducible representation of $L_1 \oplus L_2$ is a tensor product of an irrep of of $L_1$ with an irrep of $L_2$; and conversely, each such tensor product of irreps of the factors gives an irrep of the direct sum.

See e.g. [Tensor product of simple modules over semisimple Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826725/96384), or [Tensor product of irreducible representations of semisimple Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350849/96384). There are tons of questions and answers on this site for the corresponding case of groups (where of course the direct sum is replaced by a direct product).

---

Applying this to your problem we see that for *irreducible* reps, we can prolong the above chain, and identify

irreducible complex reps of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \leftrightarrow ... \leftrightarrow$ irreducible complex reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \stackrel{\text{Fact }3} \leftrightarrow$ tensor products of two irreducible complex reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \stackrel{\text{Fact }1} \leftrightarrow$ tensor products of two irreducible complex reps of $\mathfrak{su}_2$

where in the last step we just made use of the fact that $\mathfrak{su}_2$ is a real form of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. Note that since $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ is another real form of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, we could also have identified this with the tensor products of two irreducible complex reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$.

---

**Exercise:** Show that the complex irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_{\color{red}{3}}(\mathbb C)$ *viewed as a real Lie algebras* are in $1$-to$1$-correspondence with (many things, e.g.) the tensor products of two irreps of $\mathfrak{su}_{1,2}$.

Comment: Your answer has always been so helpful, both clear in appropriate extent of details and illustrating! Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @HetongXu: Thanks to your nice words, I reread this answer and actually spotted a wrong claim in it! I hope after correcting that it's more deserving of the praise.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Hi, Torsten! Could you kindly explain to this idiot here (me, that is) how a complex representation $ \rho $ of a real Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{g} $ on a complex vector space $ V $ is to be defined? How is $ \rho $ a Lie-algebra homomorphism from the *real* Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{g} $ to the *complex* Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{gl}(V) $? Thank you!

Comment: @Transcendental: From your complex vector space $V$ (of dimension $n$ say), you get $\mathfrak{gl}_{\mathbb C}(V)$, which is a complex Lie algebra. This is a complex vector space of dimension $n^2$. So it is also a real vector space of dimension $2n^2$, and the bracket still defines a Lie algebra structure so this is also a real Lie algebra. Now a representation of $\mathfrak g$ on $V$ is a homomorphism $\mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_{\mathbb C}(V)$ of real Lie algebras. (I.e. we just need to check whether it commutes with real scalars.)

Comment: (With the terminology of this very answer, to clarify things in my previous comment one should write "a homomorphism $$\rho: \mathfrak g \rightarrow R_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak{gl_\mathbb C}(V))$$ of real (!) Lie algebras.")

Comment: Alternatively, you can say it is an additive map $\rho : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow End_{\mathbb C}(V)$ such that $\rho([x,y]) = \rho(x)\rho(y)-\rho(y)\rho(x)$, and $\rho(ax) = a \rho(x)$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$.