representations of $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}) $ and indexes
The Wikipedia article Representation theory of the Lorentz group states the following

The complex linear representations of  $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{C}} $ stand in one-to-one correspondence with the real linear representations of $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}) $. The set of all real linear irreducible representations of  $ \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}) $ are, thus indexed by a pair $ (\mu, \nu) $

where do these indices come from? what do they represent? also the article latter says they take the values $ 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, ... $ why do they take these values?

What do you know about complex representations of the complex Lie algebra $sl_2(\mathbb C)$?

You might want to read through https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177437/96384 for what's going on here.

The article you linked does explain itself in more detail if you keep reading but to put it simply they are half the highest weights. The factor of a half is a physics convention.
The reason for the physics convention (I believe) is as follows. Consider representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2) \cong \mathfrak{so}(3)$. In maths we list the representations of this Lie algebra by their highest weight. Since the rank of these is 1, the weights live in a 1-dimensional space i.e. they are all scales of each other. In fact they are all positive integer scales of the "fundamental weight" so we can represent all irreducble representations by a positive integer. An important question is then which of these Lie algebra representations are also representations of $SO(3)$ and the answer is the ones with highest weight an even multiple of the fundamental weight. To make this distinction more stark, physicists halve the numbers so a representation extends to one for $SO(3)$ if the representative number is an integer. Then $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C}$ is just two copies of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ so its irreducible representations are just tensor products of an irreducible representation for each copy so can be represented by two integers (or two half integers in the physics system).
